# word comparison in a line of text in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, string-comparison

Hi I am using c# language in my project and I am trying to get output something like below.

```
 string str1 = "Cat meet's a dog has";
 string str2 = "Cat meet's a dog and a bird";

 string[] str1Words = str1.ToLower().Split(' ');
 string[] str2Words = str2.ToLower().Split(' ');

 var uniqueWords = str2Words
   .Except(str1Words)
   .Concat(str1Words.Except(str2Words))
   .ToList();
```

This gives me out put has,and ,a, bird which is correct but what i would like is something like below

> has        -    present in first string not present in second string

> and a bird -    not present in first string but present in second string

For example, second user case

```
String S1 = "Added"
String S2 = "Edited"
```

here out put should be

> Added  - present in first string not present in second string

> Edited - not present in first string but present in second string

I would like to have some indication which is present in first and not in second, present in second and not in first and comparison should be word by word rather than character by character. Can someone please help me with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest matching words

> Let word be a sequence of letters and apostrophes

with a help of *regular expression* (please, note that splitting doesn't take punctuation into account and thus `cat` `cat,` and `cat!` will be considered three different words) and then query matches for two given strings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 

...

private static readonly Regex WordsRegex = new Regex(@"[\p{L}']+"); 

// 1 - in text1, 2 - in text2, 3 - in both text1 and text2 
private static List<(string word, int presentAt)> MyWords(string text1, string text2) {
  HashSet<string> words1 = WordsRegex
    .Matches(text1)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  HashSet<string> words2 = WordsRegex
    .Matches(text2)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  return words1
    .Union(words2)
    .Select(word => (word, presentAt: (words1.Contains(word) ? 1 : 0) | 
                                      (words2.Contains(word) ? 2 : 0)))
    .ToList();
}
```

Demo:

```
string str1 = "Cat meet's a dog has";
string str2 = "Cat meet's a dog and a bird";
    
var result = MyWords(str1, str2);
    
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
    
Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
(Cat, 3)         # 3: in both str1 and str2 
(meet's, 3)      # 3: in both str1 and str2
(a, 3)           # 3: in both str1 and str2
(dog, 3)         # 3: in both str1 and str2 
(has, 1)         # 1: in str1 only
(and, 2)         # 2: in str2 only
(bird, 2)        # 2: in str2 only
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8EVT81)

If you want a wordy output:

```
string str1 = "Cat meet's a dog has";
string str2 = "Cat meet's a dog and a bird";
    
string[] options = new string[] {
  "not present",
  "present in first string not present in second string",
  "not present in first string but present in second string",
  "present in first string and present in second string"
};
        
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.word} - {options[pair.presentAt]}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
Cat - present in first string and present in second string
meet's - present in first string and present in second string
a - present in first string and present in second string
dog - present in first string and present in second string
has - present in first string not present in second string
and - not present in first string but present in second string
bird - not present in first string but present in second string
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, Suppose below is my two texts string str1 = "It is agreed on the date shown in Box 2 between the party named in Box 3 as";
        string str2 = "It is agreed on the date shown in Box 2 removed the party named in Box 3 as"; the result i would expect is 
(It, 3)
(It, 3)
(is, 3)
(is, 3)
(agreed, 3)
(on, 3)
(the, 3)
(date, 3)
(shown, 3)
(in, 3)
(Box, 3)
(between, 1)
(removed, 2)
(party, 3)
(named, 3)
(as, 3)
so i would like to preserve the order as well

Comment: @Niranjan: Are you looking for an *edit sequence* then? Having original string `"Agreed on new date shown"` and a target one `"Agreed on the old datetime shown"` you will get `Agreed (keep) on (keep) new (delete) the (insert) old (insert) datetime (edit from date) shown (keep)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
str2Words.Except(str1Words)
```

finds the words in `str2Words` that are not in `str1Words`.

```
str1Words.Except(str2Words)
```

finds the words in `str1Words` that are not in `str2Words`.

Since you need the two separately, you will need to avoid concatenating them and, instead use [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0) on each of them to get space-separated results and append the "present" addendum that you planned for them.

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad, I did this, it finds the difference but it doesnt tell me which word present in first and not in second and other way around also

Comment: @Niranjan have you tried something like `str2Words.Except(str1Words).Join(" ") + " present in first string not present in second string"`? If so, what was the result?